# Git/heroku Nightmare cant seem to reset to previous commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search, runtime-error

The title falsely implies that I slept last night. I have been up for the last two hours about to pull all my hair out. So my first ROR app was all said and done, and I thought I would make the client happy and add a STUPID calendar page that would help the admin and the payroll deparments process background investigations. This was foolhardy and completely outside my scope.

I finally finished the calendar and when I did

```
 git push heroku master
```

I got the following error in my cml

```
   Unexpected token name «t», expected punc «,» (line: 11662, col: 25, pos: 329022)
```

I scoured my entire app for a <> and couldn't didn't find one. I don't even think my app is 11,000 lines of code long. Not knowing what else to do I did a git reset to a commit in my git log labeled heroku.  I thought for sure this would fix the problem, but instead I got all these conflicts. I am new to git as welll. Eventually somehow someway through my ultimate stupidity I ended up with >>>>>>>>>>>>>>HEAD all over my code. My routing file disappeared...

So I went to my repo and copied the clone address and cloned into another folder, and pushed into another heroku remote.  Still the app was rejected after all that because of the same <> error. I don't know what to do. Thanks jp

Answer (score 0):

it was JS error I deleted all my js files and download a youtube playlist on git